# Aggregation using subquery: Error 1111 occurs. How do I fix it?

Tags: mysql, average, aggregate-functions

Please understand that I used Google Translator because I am not proficient in English.

First of all, I get error 1111 when using mysql.

The problem is to find the name of the customer whose average book table sales is higher than the average of each customer in the customer table.

Currently, the code I have written is:

1)

```
select customer.name from customer, Orders 
where avg(Orders.saleprice) < 
(select avg(Orders.saleprice) from Orders, customer 
where Orders.custid = customer.custid AND Orders.custid = 1
group by orders.custid);
```

2. 

```
select customer.name from customer, Orders, book
where avg(Orders.saleprice) < 
(select avg(Orders.saleprice) from Orders, customer 
where Orders.custid = customer.custid group by orders.custid);
```

In the case of 2), I tried to compare values at a time, but the code failed because error 1111 occurred. In the case of 1), the code was written with only one custid set to '1'.

[image]

The picture above is the average of the purchase amount of each customer in each customer table.

[image]

The picture above is the average of the sales of the book table.

This is my first time using stackoverflow recommended by a subscribed YouTuber, so I am inexperienced and English is also inexperienced, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In second case you compare number `avg(Orders.saleprice)` with table. this is impossible.   What result you desire? Do you want get customer with average customer's order greater  then common average?

Comment: That's right, this is a problem of calculating the average of the customers that are greater than the average of the Orders table (11,800) and outputting the names of the customers that are greater than the average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem by next way:

```
-- select customers with average salesprice
select 
    customers.*,
    avg(saleprice) as avgsaleprice
from customers
join orders on customers.id = orders.customer_id
group by customers.id, customers.name
-- filter result for customers having average greater then common order average 
having avgsaleprice > (
    select 
        avg(saleprice) as avgsaleprice
    from orders
);
```

Look the fiddle at [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=aa4127b0899240d77a6aeff9395aa7e0&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. What are some tips to consider or think about in solving problems with joins like this one?

And, there is one more problem similar to the article in the question.

The problem is finding books that more than 30% of all customers have purchased. An sql statement that finds 30% of all customers was derived. How do you go about counting each book?

For each book, bookid exists, and bookid exists in this form: 1,2,3,.....

Comment: You should ask new question about this problem

Comment: I used stackoverflow the day before yesterday, so the manual is unfamiliar... The answer to the question was very helpful. Finally, always be healthy and happy :)